# Properties of the uniform norm on probability spaces

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, normed-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a probability space, and $v\in \mathcal M^+(\mathcal A)$ be a positive measurable function.
I am interested in how to show that

$$
\left| \int_X v ~ \text d\mu \right|
\leq \sup\{|v(x)|~:~x\in X\}
$$

I am completely stooped, and don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Isn't this kind of from the definition? From basic calculus: $|\int_a^b f(x) dx| \le (b-a) \sup[|f(x)|]$

Comment: In a basic calculus example I can se that this is the case, but I have a hard time wrapping my head around this when working in probability spaces. I might just be confusing myself with notation, but I don't feel comfortable right now.

Comment: Also, to make my case fit your example - where are the $(b-a)$? Is it simply $(1-0)$ because we are in a probability space, or am I missing something?

Comment: Instead of $(b-a)$ it is $\mu(X)$ which is just $1$. But I don't know all you definitions and assumptions

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. What are you missing? As far as I can tell this is pretty standard notation?

Comment: I didn't complain about the notation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84069/discussion-between-toke-faurby-and-david-peterson).

Answer (score 1):

Since $v$ is positive, we don't need to take absolute values. We know that $$\int_X v\,d\mu$$ is given by the limit of the integrals of simple functions $s=\sum_{k= 0}^n a_k\chi_{A_k}\leq v$, where the coefficients $a_k$ are nonnegative and the sets $A_k$ are disjoint and measurable. Note the coefficients satisfy $a_k\leq\sup\{v(x): x\in X\}$ because $s\leq v$ on $A_k$. These integrals are equal to $$\sum_{k= 0}^n a_k\mu(A_k)\leq\max\{a_1,\ldots, a_n\}\sum_{k= 0}^n\mu(A_k)=\max\{a_1,\ldots, a_n\}\mu(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_k)\\ \leq\max\{a_1,\ldots, a_n\}\mu(X)\leq\sup\{v(x): x\in X\}$$ Thus $\sup\{v(x): x\in X\}$ is an upper bound to $\int_X v\,d\mu$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $s=\sum_{k= 0}^n a_k\chi_{A_k} \leq \int_X v \text d \mu$? Or perhaps I am a bit confused about that step - $v$ is just the function, where as $\sum_{k= 0}^n a_k\chi_{A_k}$ is an approximation of a function, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: In the defintion of the Lebesgue integral, we first define the integrals of simple functions and proceed  to define the integral of a positive measurable function as the limit of the integrals of simple functions that approximate the function, so it is a matter of definition of the integral. Refer for example to p. 202--203 of  Billingsley's Probability and measure, 1986.